# How to make expandable row in table with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make apps that show table like this, is that possible in Flutter? I mean table like this:

[image: i mean table like this]

Answer (score 0):

The flutter `Expanded` widget allows this, and can be used in tables. Have a look at this video from the flutter documentation explaining how it can be used: https://youtu.be/_rnZaagadyo